# Ng-grid doesn't update rowHeight

Tags: java, javascript, grid, height, ng-grid

I have been working on trying to find a way of changing the rowHeight in my Html so I can put my directiveA(displays grid) in multiple places with different rowHeights.  When I finally get that working I find out that it won't update on my webpage.  What I have come to is that the directiveB(sets value from html to rowHeight)

```
.directive('getHeight', function(){
    return{
        controller: 'BNotesCtrl',
        scope:{
            'rowHeight': '='
        },
        link: function(scope){
            scope.theRowHeight = scope.rowHeight;
            scope.options.rowHeight = scope.theRowHeight;
        }
    }
})
```

Anyways, as you can see it uses the controller BNotesCrtl and in that is my options for ng-grid.  And with console logs I have found out that it doesn't change the value of rowHeight until BNotesCrtl runs through once.  And by that time the grid is already drawn and no longer can be updated.  So is there a way of running through BNotesCrtl with the directive so I can update the options before it's too late?